# How to write this query in yii and print it without using foreach loop?

Tags: sql, database, yii, query-builder

I have written this query in sql and it is working fine, I am getting the exact result which I wanted, but when I write this query in Yii, and if I do not use foreach loop I get this error `array to string conversion`.
Query in sql

```
SELECT description FROM `comment_business` where review_business_id=72;
```

Query in Yii

```
 $results=Yii::app()->db->CreateCommand()  
                                ->select('description')
                                ->from('comment_business b')
                               ->where('b.review_business_id='.$ba->id)
                                ->queryRow();
     echo $results;
```

I know in sql, I get the description, but here, how can I achieve my results, without using foreach loop ?

I have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you get an only row try

```
echo $result['description'];
```

if you get more than a row you need index

```
 echo $result[0]['description'];
```

Comment: Oh how stupid I am, it was so simple, Thanks Scais sir.